# Add Point to Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, point

I'm coding in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. I need to add a point onto a `Canvas`, but I can't...

```
for (float x = x1; x < x2; x += dx)
{
    Point poin = new Point();
    poin.X = x;
    poin.Y = Math.Sin(x);
    canvas1.Children.Add(poin);
}
```

Studio says:

> Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Point' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

My question is: how do I add a point onto a `Canvas`?

Comment: The `Point` class does not represent a visual point, but is just a set of coordinates that you could use to define **where** your point should be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

From your code snippet I assume you're trying to draw a curve. To do this, you can look into `GraphicsPath`. Instead of drawing individual points, you can use the points as coordinates, which you connect through lines. Then, in your code, you can create a `GraphicsPath` using the `AddLine` method.

This could then be drawn onto a bitmap, for example.

**EDIT**

Sample (not tested):

```
GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath();

for (float x = x1; x < x2; x += dx)
{
    Point point = new Point();
    point.X = x;
    point.Y = Math.Sin(x);

    Point point2 = new Point();
    point2.X = x+dx;
    point2.Y = Math.Sin(x+dx);

    p.AddLine(point, point2);
}

graphics.DrawPath(p);
```

Another way would be to use the WPF `Path` class, which would work about the same, but is a real UI element which you can add to the children of a `Canvas`.

**EDIT**

People have pointed out that the above code is Windows Forms code. Well, here's what you can do in WPF:

```
myPolygon = new Polygon();
myPolygon.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
myPolygon.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSeaGreen;
myPolygon.StrokeThickness = 2;
myPolygon.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myPolygon.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
for (float x = x1; x < x2; x += dx)
{
    Point p = new Point(x, Math.Sin(x));
    points.Add(p);
}

myPolygon.Points = points;
canvas1.Children.Add(myPolygon);
```

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express have no System.Drawing.dll

Comment: @Anatoly: this is not a matter of the Visual Studio version you're using. System.Drawing is part of the .NET Framework. VS 2010 takes a while to asynchronously load the assemblies you can add as reference. Wait some more and sort the list by name.

Comment: @Erno: Yes, but doesn't really matter, does it? You can still use `GraphicsPath` and draw it to a bitmap, which then you show on a canvas, right? :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - I'd go for a WPF solution because I expect performace to be better. The Graphics class uses GDI and it seems such a waste to get into the whole mess of Disposing GDI objects in a WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

The `Point` you used is not a `UIElement` but a struct, please use `Line` instead.

```
Line lne = new Line();
lne.X1 = 10;
lne.X2 = 11;
lne.Y1 = 10;
lne.Y2 = 10;
canvas1.Children.Add(lne);
```

You get the idea...

**Edit**
changed:
lne.X2 = 10 to lne.X2 = 11

Comment: But how i can put it in for? Studio say: Element is already the child of another element.

Comment: it is possible only if you will try to add the same Line twice,
please add Line lne = new Line(); in for block not before that.

Comment: please remove any other code and use the code you posted, add it to Loaded event of your MainPage.
also I was wrong assuming 0 size point could work, please change lne.X2 = x ----> lne.X2 = x+1

Answer (score 1):

If it is 'just a single point you want to add, you can add a tiny rectangle or ellipse to the canvas.

If you want to set a lot of points or a couple points many times, I suggest you [create an array of pixel data (colors)](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2009/03/18/Silverlight3-WriteableBitmap.aspx) and write those to a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, the children of the `Canvas` control must be derivatives of the `System.Windows.UIElement` class: `System.Windows.Point` is not. To achieve what you are doing, you would be best looking into using the geometry within WPF. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) for an article on how to do so.

Comment: may be you can show example how add POINT , here i see only how add line

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ellipse

```
Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
myEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
myEllipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.White;
myEllipse.Width = 200;
myEllipse.Height = 100;
Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse,50);
Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse,80);
myCanvas.Children.Add(myEllipse);
```