# Efficient way to draw a single point on canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am looking for a way to draw a single point (with a color) on C# canvas. 
In android I would do something like

```
paint.Color = Color.Rgb (10, 10, 10);
canvas.DrawPoint (x, y, paint);
```

So I thought that I would be able to find it in the [Shape class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape#inheritanceContinued), but it was not there. Am I missing something or there is no way to draw a single point?

In the second case, what is a recommended way of drawing a point? In HTML5 canvas there is a similar problem and people are drawing points using [rectangles/circles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7812514/1090562).

**P.S.** a question with similar title [Add Point to Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911713/add-point-to-canvas) is not answering it and moving into "how to draw a shape".

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? Metro? Something else?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Draw a really small line maybe?

Comment: point as in what? you shall go for drawing an ellipse there.

Comment: @Amu He just wants to fill a pixel.

Comment: I would guess a Line would be the most lightweight Shape. If you want, you could derive as Dot class from Shape, but when you define a geometry, you must use one of the existing geometries such as LineGeometry. I wrote a rudimentary Dot shape just for fun and it works more or less, but I don't believe it's really useful...

Answer (score 5):

I just ran in the same question for UWP, I finally decided to use an Ellipse:

```
int dotSize = 10;

Ellipse currentDot = new Ellipse();
currentDot.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
currentDot.StrokeThickness = 3;
Canvas.SetZIndex(currentDot, 3);
currentDot.Height = dotSize;
currentDot.Width = dotSize;
currentDot.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
currentDot.Margin = new Thickness(100, 200, 0, 0); // Sets the position.
myGrid.Children.Add(currentDot);
```

Comment: Hi what is `myGrid`? Did you mean YourCanvas?

Comment: Hi FirstStep, it is actually a Grid object inside a Canvas in the XAML:
`
<Canvas>
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    </Grid>
</Canvas>`

But you probably can draw in the canvas directly, don't have time to test but I'll be surprised if it was not possible.

Comment: I see no I get what you mean, just wanted to make sure so thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about a Polyline?

xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="#00FFFFFF" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">
        <Polyline x:Name="polyline" Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="3"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

c#:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    polyline.Points.Add(new Point(0,0));
    polyline.Points.Add(new Point(0, 1));
    polyline.Points.Add(new Point(1, 0));
    polyline.Points.Add(new Point(1, 1));
}
```